# ORACLE: Updating multiple columns at once

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update two columns using the same update statement can it be done?

```
IF V_COUNT = 9 THEN
        UPDATE INVOICE
        SET INV_DISCOUNT = DISC3 * INV_SUBTOTAL
                , INV_TOTAL = INV_SUBTOTAL - INV_DISCOUNT       
        WHERE INV_ID = I_INV_ID;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('YOU QUALIFY FOR A DISCOUNT OF 30%');
```

The issue is that the `INV_TOTAL` is not updating, only the **inv_discount**

**DISC3 = 0.3** I.E 30% discount, so what ever the sub_total is will be multiplied by 0.3 and that's the value for INV_discount

INV_TOTAL = sub_total - discount

```
    INV_ID|INV_DATETIME                  |INV_SUBTOTAL|INV_DISCOUNT|  INV_TOTAL
----------|------------------------------|------------|------------|-----------
       100|14-NOV-12 09.40.06.918000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       101|18-MAR-12 10.03.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       102|18-MAR-12 10.15.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       103|18-MAR-12 10.55.00.000000     |      $80.00|       $8.00|     $72.00
       104|18-MAR-12 10.38.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       105|12-JUN-12 15.15.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       106|06-AUG-12 12.13.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       107|04-MAY-12 09.15.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       108|29-NOV-12 13.16.00.000000     |      $25.00|       $5.00|     $22.50
       109|18-MAR-12 10.37.00.000000     |      $50.00|      $15.00|     $45.00
```

**108** is suppose to be 20% of 25, the discount amount is correct but the inv_total is not, it should be $20, not $22.50

**109** is suppose to be 30% of 50 the discount amount is correct but inv_total should be $35

**103** calculates fine, which is 10% discount

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to update multiple columns in the same statement, and in fact your code is doing it.  So why does it seem that "INV_TOTAL is not updating, only the inv_discount"?

Because you're updating INV_TOTAL with INV_DISCOUNT, and the database is going to use the *existing* value of INV_DISCOUNT and not the one you change it to.  So I'm afraid what you need to do is this:

```
UPDATE INVOICE
   SET INV_DISCOUNT = DISC1 * INV_SUBTOTAL
     , INV_TOTAL    = INV_SUBTOTAL - (DISC1 * INV_SUBTOTAL)     
WHERE INV_ID = I_INV_ID;
```

Perhaps that seems a bit clunky to you.  It is, but the problem lies in your data model.  Storing derivable values in the table, rather than deriving when needed, rarely leads to elegant SQL.

Comment: Lol, that did it wasted like 10 hours on this, the only way my procedure would calculate the inv_total was executing the procedure twice. kind weird

Comment: There are still some issues, it seems to be calculating it wrong :S

Answer (score 2):

I guess the issue here is that you are updating INV_DISCOUNT and the INV_TOTAL uses the INV_DISCOUNT. so that is the issue here.
You can use returning clause of update statement to use the new INV_DISCOUNT and use it to update INV_TOTAL.

this is a generic example let me know if this explains the point i mentioned

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SingleRowUpdateReturn
IS
    empName VARCHAR2(50);
    empSalary NUMBER(7,2);      
BEGIN
    UPDATE emp
    SET sal = sal + 1000
    WHERE empno = 7499
    RETURNING ename, sal
    INTO empName, empSalary;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Name of Employee: ' || empName);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('New Salary: ' || empSalary);
END;
```